# Como usar inner join no Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, join, inner

Tenho o seguinte loop em uma tabela da view

```
@foreach ($filme as $f)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $f->fil_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $f->fil_filme }}</td>
        <td>{{ $f->fil_sinopse }}</td>
        <td>{{ $f->fil_lancamento }}</td>        
        <td>{{ $f->cat_id }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Mas só exibe o id da categoria, pois está na tabela filme. Como dar um INNER JOIN com a tabela categoria no laravel 5?

Comment: Coloque os models e o controller?

Comment: Coloca o código que gera a variável `$filme`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar o Query Builder para fazer joins

Para executar uma "junção" básica, você pode usar o método em uma instância do construtor de consultas. O primeiro argumento passado para o método `join` é o nome da tabela para a qual você precisa se juntar, enquanto os demais argumentos especificam as restrições de coluna para a junção. Claro, como você pode ver, você pode se juntar a várias tabelas em uma única consulta:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

> [LARAVEL - Banco de dados: Construtor de consultas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)

Comment: No caso, eu colocaria $f->cat_id.cat_descricao se utilizasse esse Query Builder?

Comment: Consegui. Obrigado :)

Comment: Por enquanto é só. Obrigado.